# Efficiently Accessing a 3D Array Stored as a 1D Array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, multidimensional-array, fft

I have a 3D array which is stored as a 1D array in a columnwise fashion. For example,

```
for( int k = 0; k < nk; k++ ) // Loop through the height.
    for( int j = 0; j < nj; j++ ) // Loop through the rows.
        for( int i = 0; i < ni; i++ ) // Loop through the columns.
        {
            ijk = i + ni * j + ni * nj * k;
            my3Darray[ ijk ] = 1.0;
        }
```

For my application, I need to access all the rows/columns/height of `my3Darray`. By height, I mean the vectors in the third dimension of the array. I need this because I want to process the FFT of each vector and return the resulted vector. I would be thankful to have my friends's thoughts in stackoverflow, how I can efficiently access these vectors. Of course one trivial possibility, for example, for the height vectors is:

```
for( int i = 0; i < ni; i++ ) // Loop through the columns.
    for( int j = 0; j < nj; j++ ) // Loop through the rows.
    {
        for( int k = 0; k < nk; k++ ) // Loop through the heights.
        {
            ijk = i + ni * j + ni * nj * k;
            myvec[ k ] = my3Darray[ ijk ];
            fft( myvec, myvec_processed );
        }

        // Store the results in a new array, which is storing myvec_processed in my3Darray_fft_values.
        for( int k = 0; k < nk; k++ ) // Loop through the heights.
        {
            ijk = i + ni * j + ni * nj * k;
            my3Darray_fft_values[ ijk ] = myvec_processed[ k ];
        }
    }
```

Am I computing this efficiently? Is there a possibility of passing `my3Darray` directly to the function which processes the FFT of the vectors (instead of copying the vector to `myvec`)?

Comment: Can't you make k the inner most variable so you would not jump in `ni * nj` steps but by 1, to make it cache friendly. There isn't much more you can do.

Comment: I need to calculate the FFT for all the vectors: row-wise, column-wise, as well as height-wise.

Comment: You said by height... what makes you think it's slow now, and more importantly, that it can be improved. You showed least cache friendly example (also by height btw). Again, IMO, there is not much more you can do than improving cache friendliness for the code you show. Well, let's hope I'm wrong. One thing I would actually try is, copy whole array, to reindex it. Maybe two iterations with jumps by 1 will be faster than one with big jumps, but it depends on how smart CPU cache predictor is.

Comment: You could replace the complicated multiply line with `ijk += stride;` if you compute `stride` and initialize `ijk` outside the loop.  But unfortunately, you are still going to run into cache problems if you don't access sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

When everything gets reduced to its innermost bits and bytes, your 3-dimensional array gets stored, of course, in one dimensional memory. So, given array element's three dimensions, the compiler produces pretty much the same code to calculate the location of the array element as you are doing yourself. Surprise!

So, in other words, it's pretty much the same thing.

The only thing that might work in the compiler's favor, with explicit 3-dimensional arrays, is that the compiler knows the sizes of all the inner dimensions, and if the size of the innermost dimensional slice happens to be something convenient, like a power of 2, the compiler might replace some of the multiplications with equivalent left shifts, which would be slightly faster, I suppose, then a full blown multiply instruction. But I'd be surprised if it turns out to be a large difference in performance.

It's probably more important to pick the relative order of your dimensions, so that your typical access patterns, for your transformations, will be more CPU cache-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

You can cut down on the multiplies by precomputing a stride like this:

```
...
for( int j = 0; j < nj; j++ ) // Loop through the rows.
{
    int stride = ni * nj;
    ijk = i + ni * j;
    for( int k = 0; k < nk; k++ ) // Loop through the heights.
    {
        myvec[ k ] = my3Darray[ ijk ];
        fft( myvec, myvec_processed );
        ijk += stride;
    }
}
```

But this will only speed things up a little.  You will still have cache problems due to accessing `my3Darray` in a nonsequential fashion.